# Mount a NFS shared directory as physical device in order to use extundelete

Tags: networking, mount, data-recovery, nfs, nas

I want to recover deleted files from my Synology using extundelete directly from the network.
As extundelete works only with /dev/sda physical drives, I would like to know how to mount my NFS directory in order to be viewed as a physical drive in /dev.
I already configured my Synology with NFS access and mounted in Ubuntu (/mnt) but I'm not allowed to access it from extundelete as it doesn't work on network mounted drives.
Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? Are you asking if there is some way *other than* physically removing the drive from the NAS enclosure?

Comment: Yes, exactly !! I wondered if it was possible through the network.

Answer (score 0):

Extundelete works on the actual physical device.  The devices found in the /dev/ directory are files with special characteristics.  These character and block devices relate to raw, physical hardware.

While a special type of mount, like a `bind` mount of network drives make it appear to many programs treat them, there is a difference when it comes to a program such as `format`, `fsck`, and `Extundelete` that is accessing the raw hardware.

You would have to have access through a method such as **ssh** to the NFS server and run Extundelete on the physical partition using the `/dev/[device]` argument for the recovery.

The device should be un-mounted promptly to decrease the chances of the deleted data becoming overwritten.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick feedback. So I know what to do now : remove drives from the NAS and put them in a Ubuntu tower PC ;)

Comment: You're welcome.  Why would you remove the drives?  You only have to access the drives via their device name from the computer they are physically located.  Just don't mount the drives or specific partition where the data is located.  You don't even have to touch the physical computer that contains the drives.  You can run the command remotely from any computer.  Just run the command using `/dev/sdxy` from any computer.

Comment: I need to remove drives as they are in a Synology NAS and I cannot access them from my Ubuntu laptop computer (through the network) with Extundelete (it works only with physical drives connected to the machine visible in the /dev directory) Am Iright ?

Comment: The physical device is `/dev/[devicename]`.  If you have remote shell access to the server and you have `root` access via `sudo`, then you have access to the **raw** hardware.  Taking the device out of a machine and putting it into a different machine isn't going to change the actual method needed for accessing the raw device.  You would use the same commands whether the drive is in your current server or if you put it into a different machine.  It is the **raw access commands** which is **/dev/[device]** that is needed to perform the task.... (continued)

Comment: ... It wouldn't hurt to take the drive out of the computer and put it into a different one.  But as far as time and convenience, it's not something that needs to be done, if you already have root access to the drive in the machine where it's at.  I would be curious as to why you would prefer opening up the case to do a job that you can perform without opening up the case.

Comment: ...My comments are for information only... to help clarify what is happening and what is a requirement.  Your message appears to suggest that you are spending time to open the chassis and handle the drive because you think you have to.

Comment: Dear L.D. James, in fact I think there is a misunderstanding between us ;)

Comment: In fact, I try to access my NAS remotely, from the network, using my Ubuntu laptop. I didn't try using a SSH connection, but with the NFS protocol I mounted the NAS directory I want to recover files on the Ubuntu laptop. So it doesn't appear in /dev directory.

Comment: @Dhalsim I agree concerning the misunderstanding.  This is why I asked, because I don't understand the reason for taking opening the case to take the drive out.  As far as NAS, you can't access the raw hardware using NAS.  NAS is talking to a program that is providing you the files, not the hardware.  You can access the hardware using `ssh`.  I'll gladly explain the parts that you may have some misunderstanding about.  Just like I ask question on the parts of your content which I don't understand.  ...(continued)

Comment: ...  If you type `/dev/[device]` without logging into the server using `ssh`, you a communicating with the wrong computer.  You are not accessing the hardware on the server.  If you `ssh` into the server and type `/dev/[device]` then you are accessing the raw hardware on the server.  You need to access the raw hardware.  You can access the raw hardware on any computer no matter where it's located if you type `ssh` to log into it.  While there may be other ways, using NAS isn't one of them.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have to make the job : remove disks and put them on a Ubuntu tower ;)

Comment: I just wanted to avoid this step, but ok, I was wrong ;)